# decltype for member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

How can I get the return type of a member function in the following example?

```
template <typename Getter>
class MyClass {
   typedef decltype(mygetter.get()) gotten_t;
 ...
};
```

The problem, of course, is that I don't have a "mygetter" object while defining MyClass.

What I'm trying to do is: I'm creating a cache that can use, as it's key, whatever is returned by the getter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but it seems `mygetter` is supposed to be simply any object of type `Getter`. Use `std::declval` to obtain such an object without anything else (you can only use it for type deduction)

```
typedef decltype(std::declval<Getter>().get()) gotten_t;
```

Comment: oh hey, I never knew about that.  That's awesome!  I always used `Getter().get()` and assumed that `Getter` was default constructable.